# Delphi Pascal - how to write data to file larger than 2 GB?

Tags: delphi, file, pascal

I made a tool in Delphi to create rainbow table. It was fine until file grew up to 3.1 GB. I closed my program. Then i opened it again and it crashes while executing this code:

```
Assign(RainbowFile,'Rainbow_table.txt'); {assign a text file}
Append(RainbowFile);
```

Delphi shows error "raised expection class EInOutError with message 'I/O error 131'.
My question: how to append data to existing file bigger than 2 GB.
// Obsolete
Next question:
I have currently code:

```
   Content_to_file := (#13+#10+Start_string+':'+hexstr(GTA_San_Andreas_CRC32(Start_string), 8));
   RainbowFile_handle.WriteBuffer( Content_to_file[1], Length(Content_to_file)*SizeOf(Char));
```

How to get rid of Content_to_file variable. I want put it directly to the WriteBuffer if it`s possible.

EDIT:

TFileStream works with files bigger than 2 GB. I tested it now.
However is it possible to write so:

```
RainbowFile_handle.WriteBuffer( Start_string[1]+':',
```

I mean to pass no variable argument. Or do i have definitely pass first char of variable?

EDIT 2:

I have currently made it this way:

```
    Content_to_file := (#13+#10+Start_string+':'+hexstr(GTA_San_Andreas_CRC32(Start_string), 8));
    RainbowFile_handle.WriteBuffer( Content_to_file[1], Length(Content_to_file)*SizeOf(Char));
```

Is it possible to do it without this variable?

Comment: Does your filesystem support files > 2GB?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have Windows XP 32-bit. Currently file is 3.1 GB on my NTFS partition. Problem is with my pascal code.

Answer (score 25):

You should switch to streams. A [`TFileStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TFileStream) will handle this without problems. Note that if you use random access then you must ensure you use the 64 bit versions of [`Seek`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStream.Seek) and [`Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStream.Position).

After you have opened the file stream you can seek to the end:

```
Stream.Seek(0, soEnd);
```

Then you can write lines as so:

```
procedure StreamWriteLine(Stream: TFileStream; Text: string);
begin
  Text := Text + sLineBreak;
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Text[1], Length(Text)*SizeOf(Char));
end;
```

Hopefully, that should give you enough clues to fill in the rest of the details.

Comment: The next obvious question is how to a multi-argument write() to a stream. One of the reasons I only need streams when I need to.

Comment: @Marco It wouldn't be much trouble to come up with such a routine and wrap it around an existing stream class. I personally tend not to use directly the stream classes supplied with Delphi, but instead prefer my own subclassed versions that add extra functionality to cater for my needs. In particular I have a file stream that buffers I/O for performance reasons and a memory stream that block allocates rather than demanding contiguous memory.

Comment: Then I would really like to see that. Write(lN) uses compiler magic. There are some ways maybe by messing with the textrec system, but if you do that you might as well fix the 64-bit issues directly.  Streams are IMHO simply not very comfortable for textfiles.

Comment: @Marco I expect you could do something useful with `const Args: array of const` in the manner of `Format`.

Comment: I tried once, IIRC it won't do the real formatting, you get errors on certain types of expressions, need to add [], I was short on time though, and gave up. Still it always baffled me that no standardized component was ever added. That signals to me it is not really deprecated, it just signals that E. thinks 2GB textfiles are a bad idea

Comment: @Marco: Format() is also your friend as a neat replacement for Writeln().

Comment: format is something totally different, and more like the interpreted I/O of C. Format has its uses, but writeln() substitute it is not.

Answer (score 8):

Plain procedure I/O is not suitable for modern operations. Just use `TFileStream` class, or, if you need fine control, use Windows API directly (read about [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions).

Comment: "Plain procedure I/O is not suitable for modern operations." What are these so called "modern operations" you are talking about?

Comment: @dummzeuch writing beyond 2Gb is a perfectly valid *modern* operation, and so is reading.

Comment: Translation: it is a bug, and Embarcadero doesn't seem to care.

Comment: @Marco I think they wanted to make those functions obsolete instead of "fixing" them.

Comment: @Marco @Eugene As someone who has been waiting for over 5 years for 64 bit support, as an example, I'd be very upset if Embarcadero spent time "fixing" obsolete anachronistic legacy routines instead of keeping Delphi up to date.

Comment: It might be worth a bugreport. It should be a doable fix, and comparisons with 64-bit are a bit odd since that is functionality that is close to rewriting complete parts of the compiler. Oh, and I have been compiling my Delphi code to 64-bit for 5 years now, since I hate waiting

Comment: @David +1. CodeGear has more important things to do than fixing 25+-year-old procedures.